# Failed to generate code from ABI and GraphQL schema: How to fix 'Cannot find module' error?

Tags: graphql, thegraph

When initializing graph studio I get the following error

Failed to generate code from ABI and GraphQL schema: Command failed: yarn codegen
warning ..\package.json: No license field
»   ModuleLoadError: [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] require failed to load
»   D:\Dapps\tryTheGraph\uniswap\node_modules@graphprotocol\graph-cli\dist\co
»   mmands\codegen.js: Cannot find module './_version'

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.